# Meaning of "indirectly" here

Tags: elementary-set-theory

The pictures below are taken from Kolmogorov and Fomin's Introductory Real Analysis.  Say I want to prove (7) is equivalent to $[0,1]$.

[image]

They say the best way is to prove this is "indirectly"

[image]

Then they invite us to compare this problem with problem 9.

[image]

But what do they mean by an indirect proof of problem 9?  To me, by indirect proof they mean a proof different from constructing an explicit bijection.  Are there such proofs of problem 9?  If so, please don't write out the proof, but rather explain how one would set it up.  To me this is the only way to set up a proof by contradiction for problem 9:

Suppose the real line is not equivalent to the set of all sequences of integers. Since the real line is clearly equivalent to a subset of the set of all sequences of integers, it follows from the Cantor-Bernstein theorem that the set of all sequences of integers is not equivalent to a subset of the real line.

But this doesn't seem to lead anywhere useful.

Comment: By indirect proof, one means proof by contradiction or proof by contrapositive.

Comment: I wish people would explain why they are downvoting this...

Comment: @AOrtiz I think that's actually not the case here - I think "indirect" merely refers to the use of CSB, that is, the author uses "indirect" as a piece of *natural* (as opposed to *technical*) language.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> But this doesn't seem to lead anywhere useful.

Actually, it does. You asked us to show you how to set up the problem, rather than to give a full answer, and that's commendable; but you *have* set it up correctly, so I think the right thing for me to do here is to indicate to you how to *finish* it.

The point is that there are lots of ways to find bijections between the sets $\{$infinite sequences of positive integers$\}$ and some subset of $\mathbb{R}$. The first step to doing this is to recognize that this is just a fancy way of saying "find an injection from $\{$infinite sequences of positive integers$\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$" (since this is then a bijection from $\{$infinite sequences of positive integers$\}$ to the *range* of that injection).

So to recap: **Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein** tells us that all we need to do is find injections both ways. You already know an injection in one direction, so the entire remaining task is: *find an injection from $\{$infinite sequences of positive integers$\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.* You (commendably!) don't want spoilers, so I've put one possible way to do this at the end of my answer.

---

Incidentally, although it's often used to mean "by contradiction," I interpret "indirectly" here as meaning the weaker "not constructing an explicit bijection" - and this in turn is usually, in this context, meant to suggest using Cantor-Shroeder-Bernstein. So I would rephrase the argument as:

- We have an injection from reals to sequences of positive integers (e.g., via not-eventually-all-$1$s binary expansions - but change $0$ to $1$ and $1$ to $2$ so that we actually get a sequence of *positive* integers).
- We have an injection from sequences of positive integers to reals (e.g., the one above).
- So by CSB we know that the two sets have the same cardinality.

Note that CSB [is fundamentally not constructive](https://mathoverflow.net/questions/123482/is-there-a-constructive-proof-of-cantor-bernstein-schroeder-theorem), although it doesn't use the axiom of choice. So by invoking CSB, the argument above does avoid building an explicit bijection. That said, it is easy to tweak the argument to *produce* an explicit bijection.

---

Alright, let's wrap up. I wrote above that all that's left to do is to *find an injection from $\{$infinite sequences of positive integers$\}$ to $\mathbb{R}$.* One way to do this is the following:

> For an infinite sequence $f$ of positive integers, let $Real(f)$ be the number whose binary expansion consists of $f(1)$-many $1$s, then a $0$, then $f(2)$-many $1$s, then a $0$, and so on.

As an example, $Real(1, 2,3, 4, 5, 6, ...)$ is just $$0.101101110111101111101111110...$$

It's easy to show that the map $Real$ is injective, so is a bijection between $\{$infinite sequences of positive integers$\}$ and $ran(Real)$ - and the latter is a set of real numbers, so we're done.

There are lots of similar tricks one can do (e.g. using continued fractions is much more natural, but I like the "algorithmic" feel of the construction above; also, it is easier to verify).

Comment: Is this an "indirect" proof, i.e., no explicit bijection?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd Well, do *you* see an explicit bijection between $\{$infinite sequences of positive integers$\}$ and $\mathbb{R}$ anywhere in the argument? (Spoiler alert: there isn't one.)

Comment: I don't know because I didn't read it.  I said I didn't want any proof that the reals are equivalent to the set of all sequences of integers, and just skimming through, it looks like that's what you wrote.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd "I don't know because I didn't read it." Well, you might want to do that, then. "I said I didn't want any proof that the reals are equivalent to the set of all sequences of integers" You said you wanted an answer to "explain how one would set it up" - the point of this answer is that you've *already* set it up correctly, and all that's left to do is notice the trick at the end.

Comment: Would it be possible for you to give a more general answer that explains the philosophy behind the answer?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd I don't really know what you mean by "philosophy." There's really not much to this: the philosophy is to use CSB to find injections both ways. Then we can conclude that a bijection *exists*, without having to build it. This leaves of course the effort of finding those injections, and there it's useful to keep in mind that we can define things in an ad hoc way: e.g. the injection from sequences to reals I give above isn't mathematically natural, but it's a straightforward way to get the job done. So that's the entire philosophy, so far as I can tell: (continued)

Comment: Use CSB, and in order to apply CSB, build bijections any way you can (in particular, allow yourself to do seemingly-artificial things like coding directly into the binary expansion of a number). If this doesn't satisfy you, what more are you looking for? Glancing at your other question as well as this one, it looks like you're searching for something more mysterious; I have no idea what that is, though. There's nothing particularly complicated here.

Comment: My question is much broader than just trying to find an indirect proof that the real line is equivalent to the set of all sequences of integers.  I am confused by the very idea of an indirect proof that establishes the equivalence between any two sets, i.e., a proof that doesn't construct a bijection.  I am using the problem of the real line as merely an example.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd "I am confused by the very idea of an indirect proof that establishes the equivalence between any two sets." Well, then **maybe you should read my answer**. Do you understand how CSB works? Do you understand how I construct the injection I use in my answer? If so, *that's the whole proof*. If not, which part don't you understand?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd Also, re: "My question is much broader than just trying to find an indirect proof ...  I am confused by the very idea of an indirect proof that establishes the equivalence between any two sets." Then **maybe you should ask *that***, instead of the question you did ask! What *exactly* do you find confusing about this idea?

Comment: First of all, thanks for your comments Noah.  Second, I would like to look at your answer, but I want to solve it on my own.  I am weary of using this service because of the tendencies of people to give answers over hints.

Comment: That being said, I probably don't have much choice but to look at your answer anyways.  I was just wandering if there was a more general way that you could explain it before I resorted to that.  That's all.

Comment: @SihOASHoihd I've restructured my answer to try to make it better for you. It now has three parts. The first explains why you're on the right track, and exactly what's left. The second part says a bit about indirectness in general. And the third part shows how to wrap the problem up. So you can read the first two parts, and skip the third for now.

Comment: One last question.  Do you think that the "indirect" way I started the proof is fundamentally different than any "direct" way of proving (9)?

Comment: @SihOASHoihd I think "indirect" doesn't refer to how the proof starts; rather, it refers to the use of CSB, which is (as I said in my answer) fundamentally non-constructive. By using CSB we can prove that there is a bijection without building one. Framing the argument as a proof by contradiction is unnecessary, and I doubt that's what the quoted author had in mind.